# Is there any way to reduce Delphi code / somehow to put other object into variable?

Tags: class, variables, delphi, tobject

I have

```
var objeto:TDateEdit; ...
```

If I change `as TDateEdit` in the code:

```
if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name )
```

and use this:

```
if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as objeto).name)
```

The code works.... but I need a change

```
objeto := TDBEdit;
```

I need a way to change this variable type to reduce a code
I will use

```
If (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDateEdit) then objeto := TDateEdit

If (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDBLookupComboBox) then objeto := TDBLookupComboBox
```

But the variable is

```
var objeto: TDateEdit;
```

How can I do it without repeating the code for each object type?

```
Function ValidaCampoObrigatorio(): boolean;
    var i,PrimeiroCampo,ii,indexOfItem:Integer;
    var MSGaglutinada,TIPO:string;
    var NOMEcampo : variant ;
       var objeto:TDateEdit ;
    var VALIDOU:boolean;
    
    
    
    begin
         CorERRO:=RGB(255,218,185);
         CorCertO:= 12582911;//$FF000005;
    
              
    
    Result := false;
    MSGaglutinada:='';
    PrimeiroCampo:=-1;
    tipo:='';
    NOMEcampo:='';
    
     for i := 0 to FORMULARIO.ComponentCount -1 do
      begin
    
    
      if (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDateEdit) then
       begin
    
          indexOfItem := -1;
          ii:=0;
          for ii := Low(CAMPOSnoBANCO) to High(CAMPOSnoBANCO) do
          //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
           if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name ) then
             begin
             BREAK;
             end;
             VALIDOU:=True;
           if EhRequerido[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true then
             begin
                 if((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).text = '')then
                 begin
                    if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Name)+' não pode ser NULO'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
                 end;
    
             end;
           if EhEMAIL[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if ValidEmail((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).text) = False  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Name)+' DEVE ser válido'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end;
            end ;
           if EhData[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if DataValida((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).text)=false  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Name)+' DEVE uma data Válida'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end
               else
              begin
              if (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])<=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                         if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDateEdit' end;
                          MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Name)+' não pode maior ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                          (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
              end;
              if (OperadorDataMaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])>=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                           if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDateEdit' end;
                            MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Name)+' não pode menor ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                            (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
               end;
    
    
               end;
    
    
    
    
            end ;
    
    
    
    
           if VALIDOU=true then
            begin
                      (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDateEdit).Color:= CorCertO;
            end;
           end;
    
    
    
    
    
    
      if (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDBEdit) then
       begin
    
          indexOfItem := -1;
          ii:=0;
          for ii := Low(CAMPOSnoBANCO) to High(CAMPOSnoBANCO) do
          //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
           if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name ) then
             begin
             BREAK;
             end;
             VALIDOU:=True;
           if EhRequerido[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true then
             begin
                 if((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).field.AsString = '')then
                 begin
                    if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Name)+' não pode ser NULO'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
                 end;
    
             end;
           if EhEMAIL[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if ValidEmail((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).text) = False  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Name)+' DEVE ser válido'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end;
            end ;
           if EhData[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
             if DataValida((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).text)=false  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Name)+' DEVE uma data Válida'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end
               else
              begin
              if (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])<=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                         if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                          MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Name)+' não pode maior ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                          (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
              end;
              if (OperadorDataMaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])>=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                           if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBEdit' end;
                            MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Name)+' não pode menor ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                            (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
               end;
    
    
               end;
    
            end ;
    
    
    
    
           if VALIDOU=true then
            begin
                      (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBEdit).Color:= CorCertO;
            end;
           end;
    
    
    
    
           if (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDBLookupComboBox) then
       begin
    
          indexOfItem := -1;
          ii:=0;
          for ii := Low(CAMPOSnoBANCO) to High(CAMPOSnoBANCO) do
          //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
           if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name ) then
             begin
             BREAK;
             end;
             VALIDOU:=True;
           if EhRequerido[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true then
             begin
                 if((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).field.AsString = '')then
                 begin
                    if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBLookupComboBox' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Name)+' não pode ser NULO'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
                 end;
    
             end;
           if EhEMAIL[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if ValidEmail((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).text) = False  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBLookupComboBox' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Name)+' DEVE ser válido'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end;
            end ;
    
           if EhData[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if DataValida((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).text)=false  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBLookupComboBox' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Name)+' DEVE uma data Válida'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end
               else
              begin
              if (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])<=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).text)then
                   begin
    
                         if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBLookupComboBox' end;
                          MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Name)+' não pode maior ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                          (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
              end;
              if (OperadorDataMaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])>=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).text)then
                   begin
    
                           if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBLookupComboBox' end;
                            MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Name)+' não pode menor ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                            (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
               end;
    
    
               end;
    
            end ;
    
    
    
    
           if VALIDOU=true then
            begin
                      (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBLookupComboBox).Color:= CorCertO;
            end;
           end;
    
    
    
    
           if (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TDBDateEdit) then
       begin
    
          indexOfItem := -1;
          ii:=0;
          for ii := Low(CAMPOSnoBANCO) to High(CAMPOSnoBANCO) do
          //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
           if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name ) then
             begin
             BREAK;
             end;
             VALIDOU:=True;
           if EhRequerido[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true then
             begin
                 if((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).text = '')then
                 begin
                    if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Name)+' não pode ser NULO'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
                 end;
    
             end;
           if EhEMAIL[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if ValidEmail((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).text) = False  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Name)+' DEVE ser válido'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end;
            end ;
    
           if EhData[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if DataValida((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).text)=false  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Name)+' DEVE uma data Válida'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end
               else
              begin
              if (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])<=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                         if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                          MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Name)+' não pode maior ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                          (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
              end;
              if (OperadorDataMaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])>=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                           if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                            MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Name)+' não pode menor ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                            (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
               end;
    
    
               end;
    
            end ;
    
    
    
    
           if VALIDOU=true then
            begin
                      (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TDBDateEdit).Color:= CorCertO;
            end;
           end;
    
    
    
    
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //TMaskEdit
    
    
    
           if (FORMULARIO.Components[i] is TMaskEdit) then
       begin
    
          indexOfItem := -1;
          ii:=0;
          for ii := Low(CAMPOSnoBANCO) to High(CAMPOSnoBANCO) do
          //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
           if UpperCase(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii]) = UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name ) then
             begin
             BREAK;
             end;
             VALIDOU:=True;
           if EhRequerido[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true then
             begin
                 if((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).text = '')then
                 begin
                    if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TDBDateEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Name)+' não pode ser NULO'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
                 end;
    
             end;
           if EhEMAIL[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if ValidEmail((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).text) = False  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TMaskEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Name)+' DEVE ser válido'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end;
            end ;
    
           if EhData[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)]=true  then
            begin
              if DataValida((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).text)=false  then
               begin
                     if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TMaskEdit' end;
                     MSGaglutinada :=   UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Name)+' DEVE uma data Válida'+ #13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)  ;
                     (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
               end
               else
              begin
              if (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])<=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                         if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TMaskEdit' end;
                          MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Name)+' não pode maior ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                          (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
              end;
              if (OperadorDataMaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)] <> '') then
              begin
                  if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])>=StrToDate((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).text)then
                   begin
    
                           if PrimeiroCampo<0 then begin PrimeiroCampo:=i;TIPO:='TMaskEdit' end;
                            MSGaglutinada :=  UpperCase((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Name)+' não pode menor ou igual à '+ (OperadorDatamenor[ansiindexstr((FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).name , CAMPOSnoBANCO)])+#13#10+Trim(MSGaglutinada)   ;
                            (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:=corERRO; VALIDOU:=false ;
    
                   end;
               end;
    
    
               end;
    
            end ;
    
    
    
    
           if VALIDOU=true then
            begin
                      (FORMULARIO.Components[i] as TMaskEdit).Color:= CorCertO;
            end;
           end;
    
    
        end;
    
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    if MSGaglutinada <>'' then
            begin
            MSGaglutinada:=ReplaceAll(MSGaglutinada,CAMPOSnoBANCO,CAMPOSexibirCOMO,True) ;
            MessageDlg('O(s) campo(s): '+#13#10+MSGaglutinada , mtWarning, [mbok],0 )   ;
            if TIPO='TDBEdit' then
             begin
                (FORMULARIO.Components[PrimeiroCampo] as TDBEdit).SetFocus;
             end
             else if TIPO='TDBLookupComboBox' then
             begin
                (FORMULARIO.Components[PrimeiroCampo] as TDBLookupComboBox).SetFocus
             end
               else if TIPO='TMaskEdit' then begin
                  (FORMULARIO.Components[PrimeiroCampo] as TMaskEdit).SetFocus
             end
             else if TIPO='TDBDateEdit' then begin
                  (FORMULARIO.Components[PrimeiroCampo] as TDBDateEdit).SetFocus
             end
             else if TIPO='TDateEdit' then begin
                  (FORMULARIO.Components[PrimeiroCampo] as TDateEdit).SetFocus
             end;
    
    
    
             Abort;
            end;
    
    
    
     result := true;
    
    end;
    
    
    
    function ReplaceAll(const Subject: String;
      const OldPatterns, NewPatterns: array of String;
      IgnoreCase: Boolean): String;
    var
      ReplaceFlags: TReplaceFlags;
      NewPattern: String;
      I: Integer;
    begin
      ReplaceFlags := [rfReplaceAll];
      if IgnoreCase then
        Include(ReplaceFlags, rfIgnoreCase);
      Result := Subject;
      for I := Low(OldPatterns) to High(OldPatterns) do
      begin
        if I <= High(NewPatterns) then
          NewPattern := NewPatterns[I]
        else
          NewPattern := '';
        Result := StringReplace(Result, OldPatterns[I], NewPattern, ReplaceFlags);
      end;
    end;
    
    
    
      function ValidEmail(email: string): boolean;
    
    
     var
      RegEx: TRegEx;
    begin
      RegEx := TRegex.Create('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
      Result := RegEx.Match(email).Success;
     end;
    
    
    function DataValida(StrD: string): Boolean;
    var
    DataDigitadaNoEdit:TDateTime;
    
    
    
      {Testa se uma data é valida}
      begin
        Result := true;
        try
        //ShowMessage((StrD));
        if (StrD<>'  /  /  ') and (StrD <> '  /  /    ') and (StrD <> null)  and (StrD<>'')then
         begin
             TryStrToDate(StrD,DataDigitadaNoEdit)  ;
    
         end
         else
         Begin
              Result:=False;
             // Abort;
         end;
    
    
        except
          on EConvertError do Result:=False;
        end;
      end;
       function NumeroValido(StrD: string): Boolean;
      {Testa se uma data é valida}
      begin
        Result := true;
        try
        StrToDate(StrD);
        except
          on EConvertError do Result:=False;
        end;
      end;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you reformulate your question with a minimal reproducible example so that we correctly understand what you would like to do? Try to explain your problem with simple code using English based identifiers for variables and functions so that we all understand.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to store a class type in a variable at runtime. However, you can't perform type-casts using that variable. Casts are evaluated at compile-time and must use a concrete type to cast to.

Besides, you don't really need those kind of type-casts in this situation at all.  For starters, most of your `as` casts are performing redundant type-checks that you already performed with `is`. But more importantly, `Name` is a *public* property of `TComponent` so you don't need a type-cast at all to access it, eg:

```pascal
if SameText(CAMPOSnoBANCO[ii], FORMULARIO.Components[i].Name) then
```

For other properties that are not *public*/*published* but are *protected* in a base class, like `Text` and `Color` are, you can use an accessor class to reach them, or you can use RTTI instead.

The code shown is needlessly repetitive and verbose, there are a lot of things that can be simplified in it.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
type
  TControlAccess = class(TControl)
  end;

function ValidaCampoObrigatorio(): Boolean;
var
  i, ii: Integer;
  MSGaglutinada: String;
  VALIDOU: Boolean;
  Comp: TComponent;
  Ctrl, PrimeiroCampo: TWinControl;

  function GetControlText(ACtrl: TControl): String;
  begin
    Result := TControlAccess(ACtrl).Text;
    // alternatively:
    // Result := TypInfo.GetStrProp(ACtrl, 'Text');
  end;

  procedure SetControlColor(ACtrl: TControl; AValue: TColor);
  begin
    TControlAccess(ACtrl).Color := AValue;
    // alternatively:
    // TypInfo.SetOrdProp(ACtrl, 'Color', AValue);
  end;

begin
  CorERRO := RGB(255, 218, 185);
  CorCertO := 12582911;//$FF000005;

  Result := False;

  MSGaglutinada := '';
  PrimeiroCampo := nil;
    
  for i := 0 to FORMULARIO.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    Comp := FORMULARIO.Components[i];
    if not (Comp is TWinControl) then Continue;
    Ctrl := TWinControl(Comp);

    //LOCALIZANDO DENTRO da matriz
    ii := AnsiIndexText(Ctrl.Name, CAMPOSnoBANCO);

    VALIDOU := True;

    if EhRequerido[ii] then
    begin
      if (GetControlText(Ctrl) = '') then
      begin
        MSGaglutinada := UpperCase(Ctrl.Name) + ' não pode ser NULO' + #13#10 + Trim(MSGaglutinada);
        VALIDOU := False;
      end;
    end;

    if EhEMAIL[ii] then
    begin
      if not ValidEmail(GetControlText(Ctrl)) then
      begin
        MSGaglutinada := UpperCase(Ctrl.Name) + ' DEVE ser válido' + #13#10 + Trim(MSGaglutinada);
        VALIDOU := False;
      end;
    end;

    if EhData[ii] then
    begin
      if not DataValida(GetControlText(Ctrl)) then
      begin
        MSGaglutinada := UpperCase(Ctrl.Name) + ' DEVE uma data Válida' + #13#10 + Trim(MSGaglutinada);
        VALIDOU := False;
      end
      else
      begin
        if (OperadorDatamenor[ii] <> '') then
        begin
          if StrToDate(OperadorDatamenor[ii]) <= StrToDate(GetControlText(Ctrl)) then
          begin
            MSGaglutinada := UpperCase(Ctrl.Name) + ' não pode maior ou igual à ' + OperadorDatamenor[ii] + #13#10 + Trim(MSGaglutinada);
            VALIDOU := False;
          end;
        end;
        if (OperadorDataMaior[ii] <> '') then
        begin
          if StrToDate(OperadorDatamaior[ii]) >= StrToDate(GetControlText(Ctrl)) then
          begin
            MSGaglutinada := UpperCase(Ctrl.Name) + ' não pode menor ou igual à ' + OperadorDatamenor[ii] + #13#10 + Trim(MSGaglutinada);
            VALIDOU := False;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    if not VALIDOU then
    begin
      if PrimeiroCampo = nil then PrimeiroCampo := Ctrl;
      SetControlColor(Ctrl, corERRO);
    end
    else
      SetControlColor(Ctrl, CorCertO);
  end;

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
  if MSGaglutinada <> '' then
  begin
    MSGaglutinada := ReplaceAll(MSGaglutinada, CAMPOSnoBANCO, CAMPOSexibirCOMO, True);
    MessageDlg('O(s) campo(s): ' + #13#10 + MSGaglutinada, mtWarning, [mbok], 0);
    PrimeiroCampo.SetFocus;
    Abort;
  end;

  Result := True;    
end;
```

Comment: Need change to function to return a value;procedure GetControlText(ACtrl: TControl): String;
  begin
    Result := TControlAccess(ACtrl).Text;
    // alternatively:
    // Result := TypInfo.GetStrProp(ACtrl, 'Text');
  end;

  procedure SetControlColor(ACtrl: TControl; AValue: TColor);
  begin
    TControlAccess(ACtrl).Color := AValue;
    // alternatively:
    // TypInfo.SetOrdProp(ACtrl, 'Color', AValue);
  end;

Comment: You make may day easy. was exact what I Expect. better

Comment: have any way to order component ?

Comment: @RafaelMeloReis "*Need change to function to return a value*" - fixed. "*have any way to order component ?*" - what do you mean?